# Utilizar viewBox em SVG

Tags: svg

Utilizei SVG para criar objetos. O problema é que ao mudar de janela, o SVG é cortado, só consigo ver uma parte. Quero utilizar o viewBox para mostrar todo o SVG dependente da janela ou resolução de imagem.

```
<svg width="980" height="500" viewBox="0 0 900 500">
```

Comment: Já viste esta pergunta -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49938/129 ?

Comment: O viewBox não faz isso?